# how are xamarin service methods like OnServiceCreated() called ?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

What i want to know is that when i create a Service.cs file and use BoundServices how are the methods like OnServiceCreate(), OnServiceDestroy() invoked ?

Comment: These are overrides to the base service class, they're part of the life cycle of an Android service, look at http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/components/services.html for more info

Comment: thanks for the answer!!